# How can i unit test the dependency method

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

It's my code written in Typescript; 
I want to test the private `getFunc` method and the method of `redisClient` have been called Once.
I use supertest to invoke the API, but I can't expect the redis method.

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import * as redis from "redis";
const redisOption: redis.ClientOpts = {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 6379,
    detect_buffers : true,
    db: 0,
   retry_strategy: () => 60000
}
const redisClient: redis.RedisClient = redis.createClient(redisOption);

export class IndexRoutes {
    public router: Router;
    constructor() {
        this.router = Router();
        this.init();
    }
    public init() {
        this.router.get("/",  this.getFunc);
    }
    private getFunc = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        return res.status(200).send(await redisClient.set("test", "123"));
    }
}
```

> error: Uncaught AssertionError: expected get to have been called
>   exactly once, but it was called 0 times

Help me, how do I properly stub the redisClient.get(...) function?

Comment: It would be great if you add your unit test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't usually test dependencies/dependency methods. You only test your code.

Secondly, I think you're saying you want want to check if `redis.get()` is being called or not. That means you'll have to `spy` on it.

`jest.spyOn()` is something you should check out.

Your test should look something like:

```
import * as redis from 'redis';

describe('my redis wrapper', () => {
  it('Should call get when my wrapper\'s getFunc is called', () => {
    let myRedisSpy = jest.spyOn(redis.prototype, 'get');
    // call your function here
    expect(myRedisSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
  });
});
```

Or something similar, I don't know if this code will work as is. But, you're always welcome to try.